# How do I show a notification pop up during a long method? trigger client side load mid method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I have a complex data pull that is activated when someone selects a certain value on a dropdown list. Because of how long this data pull takes I want to have a pop up that says "Please wait loading". However the popup does not appear until after the dataload completes even though I make it a background process.. I know I must not understand something but I am not sure what.

```
    protected void ddlRequestType_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ddlRequestType.SelectedValue == "7")
        {

            BackgroundWorker bg = new BackgroundWorker();
            bg.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bg_PullData);
            bg.RunWorkerCompleted += new 
            RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bg_RunWorkerCompleted);

            // Start the worker.
            bg.RunWorkerAsync();
            trInventoryItemID.Visible = true;
            trItemDescription.Visible = true;
            rnloading.Show();

        }
        else
        {
            trInventoryItemID.Visible = false;
            trItemDescription.Visible = false;
        }

    }

    private void bg_PullData(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        var dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataTable.Load(InventoryItem.GetInactiveInventory(ddlClients.SelectedItem.Text));
        txtInventoryItemID.DataSource = dataTable;
        txtInventoryItemID.DataTextField = "PieceCode";
        txtInventoryItemID.DataValueField = "Descrip";
        txtInventoryItemID.DataBind();
    }
    private void bg_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        // Retrieve the result pass from bg_DoWork() if any.
        // Note, you may need to cast it to the desired data type.
        object result = e.Result;

        // Close the loading notification.
        //rnloading.AutoCloseDelay = 10000;
    }
```

The method Show() should show notification when page is loaded on client. So then I would think because it is an autopostback at the end of ddlRequestType_SelectedIndexChanged1 would cause it to appear?

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: The thing you're forgetting is the basic nature of a web application. You're familiar with HTTP requests and responses, right? Just because you're doing an ASP.NET Web Forms app doesn't change that. User requests a page (or does some action to trigger a postback) which sends an HTTP request to the server, the server processes the request, and then sends an HTTP response. It doesn't maintain an active connection to keep sending updates to the client for a long term process.

Comment: If you want to push updates to to the client in realtime, you'll want to check out SignalR. But then again - why are you adding new functionality to a Web Forms app? Web Forms is dead.

Comment: @mason Thanks, I was hoping that since the background task allowed the method to complete that it would fire a postback and then the background would cause another but I'm not surprised that doesn't happen.

Yeah I am working on a large intranet that is built on Web Forms so I am just having to hack things.

Comment: If you have long running tasks, then executing them in the context of a web application isn't ideal. Web apps are good at processing HTTP requests, not good for long running background tasks. Generally such background work should happen in a service application (like a Windows Service or on Linux a daemon), or perhaps as part of a serverless setup (such as OpenFaaS). Your web app would communicate with the background worker via some sort of queue, such as RabbitMQ or Azure Service Bus.

Answer (score 0):

The client doesn't see any results on their end until everything server side in the ddlRequestType_SelectedIndexChanged1 is completed, because that's how postbacks work, so unless you have a way to update without a postback, I don't know of a way to do a "wait" message. If you want to do something like this, you'll have to handle it on the front end with javascript. That way you can pop up the message, then load the data into the dropdown with ajax or something in the background, and then close the message when that ajax request completes, all without a postback. There should be plenty of resources out there about how to load data with ajax if you want to go that route, but it will be a significant change to how your page works.